# How we remove all UIView component from the uiview

Tags: iphone

I am using a UIView on that i am using many controls like Button, Textbox, Label and other through coding.
I want to remove all these controls from the UIView through coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[mySubview removeFromSuperview];
```

if you kept reference (or outlet).

```
for (UIView *i in view.subviews)
    [i removeFromSuperview];
```

if you want remove all subviews from a view.

May be you want to remove subview temporarily? In this case you don't need to remove it. Property hidden set to YES makes view invisible:

```
mySybview.hidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for (UIView *subView in self.view.subviews) {
        [subView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: i want to remove controls only not the whole UIView, through this we will remove whole UIView.

Comment: nope, this is correct. this will remove the subviews but not the view itself.

Comment: i want only controls remove not the subview but here we are removing the subview

Comment: UIControl's are subclasses of UIView - and they are subviews. the code by bitmapdata.com below shows how to check for certain class types.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) 
{
     if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
     {
         UIButton *button = (UISlider *)view;

         [button removeFromSuperView];
     }

     else if([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
     {
         UILabel *label = (UILabel *)view;

         [label removeFromSuperView];
     }
     else
     {
       ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to IOS developper library, UIButton (TextBox...) are UIControl. They inherit UIView. So you can use `[myButton removeFromSuperview]`

Comment: Ya you are right but with this we can only remove the button, I want to remove all controls from the UIView.

Comment: maybe you can just use Wayne Hartman loop and add a condition :  if([subView isKindOfClass: [UIControl class]]) {
     [subView removeFromSuperview];
 }